# finding date after specific text (oracle)

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to extract a date  after a specific string (we will call it IMP for now in a text field. It may appear upper/lower case and show as `IMP 1/1/10` or `IMP happened on  1/1/10` or  `IMP-1/1/10`

So for example code below-

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc 3/4/16 blah blah IMP 3/7/16',
                '(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})') "REGEXP_SUBSTR" from dual
```

Will get the first date but not the one I want- 
I have tried

`'(IMP) (.|(a-z){1-10}) (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})'`

and other permutations.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc 3/4/16 blah blah IMP 3/7/16',
                '(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})') "REGEXP_SUBSTR" from dual
```

If I include the `(IMP) (.|(a-z){1-10})` I get null results, if I just use the
`'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})')` I get the first date that appears

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah IMP 3/7/16'                     from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2'      from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'xxx 3/5/18 ccdd 234 imp happened on 5/8/19 some 23f' from dual union all
  5     select 4, '3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13 x'         from dual
  6    )
  7  select id,
  8    regexp_substr(substr(col, instr(lower(col), 'imp ') + 4), '\d+/\d+/\d+') result
  9  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 3/7/16
         2 2/8/15
         3 5/8/19
         4 3/9/17

SQL>
```

Comment: Boo-ya!  Thanks!  This worked like a charm!  Many Thanks again!

Comment: Quick question- what does +4 do per se?  I think that is  within 4 words per se? Something I caught is where there is entire string of text between keyword IMP and the date-Thanks again-

Comment: In this context, it means "take a substring which starts at position where "imp" is found, plus 4 characters". Why? Because "imp" has 3 characters, plus 1 character for a space.

Comment: thanks-Is there is way to limit the string to certain number of characters (20?) so that if it doesn't find a date-it stops then?

Comment: Yes; that would be substr's 3rd parameter, e.g. `substr(col, instr(lower(col), 'imp ') + 4, 20)`

Comment: Thanks again @Littlefoot

Comment: No problem ; I'm glad if it helped.